# How to display .json file on webpage when it's in a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Is there a way to manipulate and display the data in the file without using fetch? In addition, can I store the json file in a variable and iterate through it? It just seems that for a local file there would be a simpler method of working with/displaying the data...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="styles.css">
    <script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="animals.json"></script> <!-- added json file-->
</head>
<body>

<div class ="sampleDiv"></div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

json file

```
[
    {
      "name": "Whiskers",
      "species" : "cat",
      "foods": {
        "likes": ["celery", "strawberries"],
        "dislikes": ["carrots"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Woof",
      "species" : "dog",
      "foods": {
        "likes": ["dog food"],
        "dislikes": ["cat food"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Fluffy",
      "species" : "cat",
      "foods": {
        "likes": ["canned food"],
        "dislikes": ["dry food"]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The browser is going to interpret that file as JavaScript. It won't do anything useful, because it's an array initializer whose value doesn't get saved to anything usable.

Answer (score 3):

`<script>` elements are for loading JavaScript, **not** JSON.

`<script src="animals.json"></script>` is just going to cause the browser to throw [a CORB error](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/) when it doesn't get the content-type it is expecting.

Use the `fetch` API to load the JSON instead.

```
fetch("animals.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Work with your data here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just put the JSON file in a js file with parsing `const yourJSON = JSON.parse(/*paste your entire JSON*/)` and then add the js file in script tag so you can accesses yourJSON variable in the other js files.

Comment: There's really no reason to use `JSON.parse()`, because JSON is already valid JavaScript. `const object = /* JSON */;` is enough.

Comment: If you want to use it without parsing then just paste the JSON file content into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load .json files as scripts. You'll need JavaScript code and an HTTP request to load it. This can be done easily by `fetch()`, but if you're just looking for an alternative, you can use jQuery's [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('animals.json', function(obj) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('sampleDiv')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

In my opinion, the most elegant way to do it is with `fetch()`. Dumping the whole json in the JavaScript code and using JSON.parse makes everything extremely unmaintainable and using jQuery is overkill, too.

Comment: you can keep using jQuery inside function: $('.sampleDiv').html(JSON.stringify(obj))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch local json using pure js, for this purpose use a node web server. If you just want to use your data without any need of mutation,
you can just create a `data.json` file containing your animals.

```js
const animals = [
    // Your animals here
]
```